# For my POST method i used Threads User multiple but actually when i run jmeter record will added only single time

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, api-testing, performance-testing

**I have created Thread Group with 5 number of users, but in actual when I run my POST method then record add only single time, but I want to add 5 records in a single run to check performance for POST method.**
[image: Thread Group]

[image: User Defined Variable]

[image: HTTP Request]
[image: Final Result added]

I'm new to JMeter please help to get out of this problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documentations](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#where) says:

> Configuration elements are processed by a separate thread. Therefore functions such as __threadNum do not work properly in elements such as User Defined Variables.

That's why `{__UUID()}` does not work in [UDV](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) too.

Check responses in your [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) Listener, that's way you can debug your test and see requests and responses to know why only one record created.

According to your first screen, you have 5 Threads and 2 in Loop count, so there are should be 10 records, not 5, actually.

Comment: thank you for your response, i have checked Result Tree in this total count are 10 but in all 10 record same value is going, and yes sorry it will count 10 not 5, my bad.  **see image above i have attached of View Result Tree**

Comment: unique_user_id generated only once.

Comment: Generate your ID directly in the AddBranch parameter Name - change its value from ${unique_user_id}_Testing to ${__UUID()}_Testing

Comment: Thank you @VadimYanguaev it's worked for me, i was looking for this.